# Who is the UK Prime Minister's spokesman?

Tags: united-kingdom, media

The Prime Minister has a spokesman, regularly quoted in newspapers.

- > Mrs May spoke to the Queen on the phone on Easter Monday to let her know of the election plan, the **prime minister's official spokesman** said. She also got the full backing of the cabinet before calling the election. http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-39629603
- > Asked by journalists on Monday whether a Naval taskforce would be sent to defend Gibraltar, **the Prime Minister's spokesman** said: "That isn't going to happen." http://www.birminghammail.co.uk/news/midlands-news/were-not-going-war-spain-12837126
- > Asked this morning if the UK was considering joining in America's military action, the **Prime Minister's Spokesman** repeatedly said "Our focus is on a political solution". http://www.itv.com/news/2017-04-10/will-the-uk-join-americas-military-action-in-syria/

Who are they? What's their name? Are there any published video or audio recordings of them giving statements? Are they ever seen with the Prime Minister, or do they only meet in private?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [position is currently held](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Minister%27s_Official_Spokesperson) by Max Blain

---

It was formerly held by **James Slack**.

He was [appointed to this position on 10 February 2017](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/prime-ministers-official-spokesperson-appointed-james-slack) after [his predecessor Helen Bower](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/new-prime-ministers-official-spokesperson-announced) took up a new role as Director of Communications in the Foreign and Commonwealth Office.

---

The role of the spokesperson is as follows [according to politics.co.uk](http://www.politics.co.uk/reference/prime-minister-s-official-statement):

> The Prime Minister's Official Spokesman or PMOS is a civil servant **charged with presenting the Prime Minister and the Government to the media in the best light possible**, whilst maintaining the independence and objectivity of the Civil Service. The **PMOS briefs press and broadcast journalists most weekdays when Parliament is sitting, giving the Prime Minister's line on current affairs as well as advance notice of government announcements due that day**. Towards the end of the week, a briefing is given for correspondents from the Sunday papers.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*

---

Comment: Thanks! Are they actually invisible? The photo in that article is just a door!

Comment: @ColonelPanic Lol, [here's the only picture](http://www.pressgazette.co.uk/daily-mail-political-editor-james-slack-confirmed-as-pms-new-official-spokesperson/) of him that I could find

Comment: I've updated to 2021 info.  Hope that's okay.